# Pasting mm:ss into excel - gets mistakenly formatted as hh:mm

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste

If I paste a dataset including times in mm:ss format into excel, how can I prevent it from interpreting them as hh:mm?  Changing the number format before or after pasting doesn't help, Excel still sees them as hours and minutes rather than minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have completed the paste, divide the result by **60**
This will convert 12 hours,34 minutes into 12 minutes,34 seconds.

Or to use a formula:

```
=TIMEVALUE("00:" & TEXT(A1,"hh:mm"))
```

[image]